# Talend import, transform a raw file and export to CSV

Tags: excel, schema, transformation, talend

My data consists of 6 million rows. There is no file extension. Would like to export it to a csv by adding a column of "UPC" which is a combination of 4 fields. 
input format:

[the raw file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix9Tx.jpg)

REQUIRED OUTPUT FORMAT in CSV

[transformed raw file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtLMd.jpg)

UPC = SY + GE + VEND + ITEM

Opened it with Excel but because it is more than 6 million rows, it gets truncated at 1 million rows.
I have an issue with talend's schema since the there is no delimiter.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. You can use the tFileInputPositional to read your file, and then output with tFileOutputDelimited after having done your transformation. If you need more help, then please show what you have already tried, and you are more likely to get the help you need.

Comment: That worked perfectly.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create a metadata columns manually (if you import the file, since it is a huge file talend gets hanged). So create the column names in a metadata (verify first snap shot).  Once done, drag the metadata as a tFileInputDelimited and make sure you provide delimiter as space (verify second snap shot). In tmap create new port and concatinate the columns as required  SY + GE + VEND + ITEM and pass it to a tFileOutputDelimited where you should provide delimeter as , . Let me know if you face any issues.  [image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Since there were issue with uneven space distribution there was an error in this method. Thank you for the answer though. Used this in another problem i came across.